# How do I define a template member function outside of a full specialized template class's definition?

Tags: c++, templates

The following code can be build successfully.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct Foo
{
    template <class S>
    void print(const T& t, const S& s);
};

template <>
struct Foo<int>
{
    template <class S>
    void print(const int& t, const S& s)
    {
        cout << s << " " << t << endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    string str("hello");
    Foo<int> foo;
    foo.print(7, str);
    return 0;
}
```

But if I move the definition of the member function `Foo<int>::print(...)` outside the definition of the class `Foo<int>` like below

```
template <>
template <class S>
void Foo<int>::print(const int& t, const S& s)
{
    cout << s << " " << t << endl;
}
```

I got a GCC compiling error like this:

```
error: too many template-parameter-lists
 void Foo<int>::print(const int& t, const S& s)
      ^
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

§14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec]/p5:

> Members of an explicitly specialized class template are defined in the
>   same manner as members of normal classes, and not using the
>   `template<>` syntax. The same is true when defining a member of an
>   explicitly specialized member class. However, `template<>` is used in
>   defining a member of an explicitly specialized member class template
>   that is specialized as a class template.

`print` is not a class template. Hence, remove the `template <>`:

```
template <>
struct Foo<int>
{
    template <class S>
    void print(const int& t, const S& s);
};

template <class S>
void Foo<int>::print(const int& t, const S& s)
{
    cout << s << " " << t << endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59f3f417dc2ca0cf).

---

Note that if you do not explicitly specialize `Foo<int>`, but tries to define `Foo<int>::print` directly, then you are explicitly specializing a member of a particular implicit instantiation of `Foo`, and not defining a member of an explicit specialization. For that, you need `template <>`:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo
{
    template <class S>
    void print(const T& t, const S& s);
};

template <>
template <class S>
void Foo<int>::print(const int& t, const S& s)
{
    cout << s << " " << t << endl;
}
```